# Why does our GAN training produces an error if some days before everything was running?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, vgg-net, generative-adversarial-network

We have a strange problem. We trained a GAN in colab for deblurring pictures. the last week(s) there wasn't any problem while train it, but since 2 days we cant continue the training: We didn't change anything in the code, but it stops directly and produces some value error. We tried to use an old version to be sure that nobody didn't change something in the code and it produces the same error.. so I guess that it's a bug or something like this?!
Maybe someone could help us =)

you could take a look at this link to colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JKj7z1V9okh0oOMaJHbGD-XjQb60SvKz#scrollTo=fbXb5vGiHVfW

We noticed one thing: during the time when everything worked well we saw an output after the block where we loaded the vgg16. the output was something with "downloading weights for VGG16".
Since the training produces this error we don't have this output after this block but we see it after the training block.

This is the error code we have:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-02c2f540d6da> in <module>()
      1 # Training the model
      2 #tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True) # works with the first 1% but then gives an error again
----> 3 loss = training(70, 1)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-12-75142a1d818a>:11 perceptual_loss  *
        vgg = VGG16(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = img_shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/vgg16.py:144 VGG16  **
        img_input)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:926 __call__
        input_list)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1098 _functional_construction_call
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2643 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py:204 build
        dtype=self.dtype)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:614 add_weight
        caching_device=caching_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py:750 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
        **kwargs_for_getter)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py:145 make_variable
        shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:260 __call__
        return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:221 _variable_v1_call
        shape=shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:702 invalid_creator_scope
        "tf.function-decorated function tried to create "

    ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call. ```
````

Comment: This seems likely to be a change in TensorFlow 2.3. [See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#variables).

Comment: Did it work? I'm stuck at the same point.